# heroku : @echo: command not found

Tags: heroku, git-bash, heroku-cli

I'm trying to install the heroku cli locally on win 7 -64 bit. I downloaded and ran the installer at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#windows. I can see that the path E:/Heroku1/bin/ has been added to PATH. Using git-bash I try:

```
$ heroku -v
/e/Heroku1/bin/../client/bin/heroku.cmd: line 1: @echo: command not found
/e/Heroku1/bin/../client/bin/heroku.cmd: line 3: fg: no job control
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that I may have been using an outdated git-bash. At this point in time they recommend using Git 2.8. I added the following to my path and it started working:

```
C:\Git28\bin;C:\Heroku\bin
```

Comment: hey bro, git current version is 2.35. you have written 2.8 version